# Concatenating a list of prefetch datasets in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a list of prefetch datasets which I would like to concatenate into a large dataset. Is there a way to do this?

```
[<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((32, None), (32, 50)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>,
 <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((32, None), (32, 50)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>,
 <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((32, None), (32, 50)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>]
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#concatenate

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `dataset1 = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).